# system of differential equations 3 DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

```
dS/dt = a - dS - λ S I + β R
dI/dt = λ S I - (d + m)I     
dR/dt = m I- (d + β)R
```

> Solve the above equation and plot the curve.

Comment: welcome to MSE. You question as written will be regarded as "homework"/"please do" and users will not answer. If this is a mathematical question about a version of SIR epidemic model then you should post on Math stackexchange. If it relates to Mathematica, I suggest you try to code this system and edit the question with any specific problem. In its current form it will not attract responses.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have not documented the values of the parameters. As for the Lorentz 3D equation, there is no closed form solution. Here is the simple code for which you asked --- obviously, your question was asked in a cavalier manner.

```
 a = 1;
 d = .2;
 λ = .3;
 m = .4;
 β = .5;
 u = 1;
 v = 1;
 w = 1;

 s = NDSolve[{S'[t] == 
 a - d S[t] - λ S[t] l[t] + β R[t], 
 R'[t] ==  m l[t]  - (d + β)  R[t], 
 l'[t] ==  λ S[t] l[t] - (d + m) l[t], S[0] == u, 
 l[0] ==  v, R[0] ==  w}, {S, l, R}, {t, 0, 400}]
```

You can either plot

```
Plot[{S[t], l[t], R[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

or

ParametricPlot3D[ {S[t], l[t], R[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 100}]

[image]